# Last Observation Carried Forward (na.locf) on Panel (cross section) Time Series

Tags: r

Is there a way to use na.locf functions to fill in NA values in a cross section (panel) time series data.

I have a panel dataset setup similarly to years of data, setup similarly to the following:

```
library(zoo) #actual [r] code and data!
library(plm)
data(Produc)
a<-data.frame(Produc)
b<-subset(a,state=="WYOMING"|state=="WISCONSIN",select = state:hwy)  #limit to an easy subset)
```

The data has suppression (ie missing values not released by the government data agency) and I'd like to just pull next observations to fill in NA values.

```
b[[2,4]]<-NA
b[[17,4]]<-NA
b[[18,3]]<-NA
c<-na.locf(b,na.rm=FALSE,fromLast=FALSE)
```

Using the na.locf function will fill the NA's but nothing will stop it from pulling data incorrectly to fill in a city's last year with the next city's first year data.I am beginning to think that I need to split the dataframe into individual city frames.

Comment: Can you create a small example data-set that shows what you mean by "year-to-year suppression" etc ? That would help get your question answered.

Comment: -1  Vague / unclear.  Data is not usable or suficiently illustrative.  Desired output not shown.

Comment: What is needed is data that can be read into R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suspect, the easiest way will be to have either to partition your data frame into separate data frames along either the City or Year dimension (using eg `split`), use `na.locf`, and then `unsplit`.

Alternatively it might be easier if you structure your data with City being the rownames, and Year the colnames (or vice-versa), and have a list of matrices for each datum. In this case you just use apply to forward-fill across the appropriate dimension.

Comment: Ahah! Finally _groked_ a little bit of ddply!
'plyr<- ddply(b,c("state"),function(df) na.locf(df,na.rm=FALSE,framLast=TRUE)'

Answer (score 2):

Building on AzadA's comment

ddply identifies a specific subset within a data frame and applies the desired function to all of the pieces in that subset by levels of the variable(s) you choose.

library(plyr)
new.data<-a$(vars you want to apply the function to, and vars needed for order and subset) 
format: ddply(data.frame,var(s) to be subset,function, further function commands)

new.data<- ddply(a,a$city,na.locf) #apply na.locf by city in vector order to all vars

a$b <- new.data$b #  do this for each variable to swap in new information for old

For more info: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/plyr.pdf